# is there a way to use Popover for lighitng data table specific column?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am displaying Wrapper data in lighting component using the data table, But I want to make popover for each field with the associated record id so that user can navigate to that record, what is the best way for that, please share an example if you have.

Comment: are you using LIghtning:Datatable component tag?

Comment: Yes I am using Lightning:Datatable tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: **NO**

you can see the supported column types [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) and you cannot add other components:

[image]

In the future, you could add a custom cell template, which I believe will help with your requirement, so it will be possible - look [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_components_roadmap.htm&type=5) and see that `lightning:dataTable (custom cell templates)` is planned for spring 19 (which is next release)

Comment: Does anybody know if this feature was released in Spring '19? I couldn't find any documentation for this.

Comment: @VinodRondla according to the docs, this feature is not available yet - for lightning aura components, BUT - according o the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) it is available for the lightning web component