# Need Help with custom types in Lightning DataTable - LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, css, lightning-design-system

Here is the playground link to the code - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/l_0ieW-Sm/17/edit

My use case is to show popover on hover for a specific column in a Data Table. Used Custom data types in Lightning Data Table for this but it is not working.

Need your suggestions to implement this.

Similar Stack Exchange Question - [is there a way to use Popover for lighitng data table specific column?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237327/is-there-a-way-to-use-popover-for-lighitng-data-table-specific-column)

Comment: Hello @HowdyRanger sorry the playgroud link is not redirecting correct. I was trying the same thing but when I add the onmouseover and onmouseevent in my custom html template. I am not able to catch the events in the customDatatable component js. How did you manage to capture the mouseover and mouseout events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this [Playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/l_0ieW-Sm/32/edit)

- You should not really use slots in custom component. Instead you should be using `@api` properties so that data can be passed while declaring the `columns` .
- Popover cannot really come out of the table cell (and float above table). This is because of [overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513382/absolute-position-and-overflowhidden) styling on parent elements which are standard - and there is nothing we can do .
- The example is working fine - only that when you hover over the cell, the popover will increase the height of row to show itself.

Comment: The playground links are not redirecting correctly. Always redirected to "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components" for both playground links in the question and the answer. Does anybody know why?

Comment: @ShreyasD yes and sorry for that.. Salesforce has deprecated its playground, so all the legacy links would just redirect to component library