# Rich Text Area in Lightning Datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-datatable

I have a lwc component having a standard lwc datatable. However, my datatable has an url field which needs to be displayed as a url. However, that particular field is coming up as the following format

```
  http://<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">b13</a>
```

I understand that this is because in datatables everything is rendered as text and never as a rich text. I am looking for any alternative ways to display the url in the correct format

I have tried using custom datatype by using the following sample

https://gist.github.com/loktevich/044d9411985c03a314765dbe05328eb3

but I am getting resolution errors tying to implement it.

Failed to resolve import "./richTextColumnType.html"

So if anyone has any working examples for displaying richtext fields in datatable. That would be really helpful.

Comment: Does https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324624/lwc-datatable-with-custom-data-type-not-rendering-as-supose/324627#324627 answer your question?